# Find the next row fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm using fgetcsv to open some data. I can display the current row but how do you then display certain data about the next row within the current row?

```
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo $data[2];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you read the next row as well. Just a thought.

Comment: Or even all the rows beforehand. Alternatively keep a `$current` and `$last` row buffered;

Comment: There's no way to peek ahead. You can't do anything with a row until you read it.